# a start job is running for wait unti snapd is fully seeded - 18.04 install

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am attempting to install 18.04 from a USB stick. The system sits timing with the following message:

```
A start job is running for wait until snapd is fully seeded xxxmins / no limit
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UNetbootin to make usb bootable, change use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) instead.
UNetbootin has many errors.