# Cannot enter GUI with "finished wait until snapd is fully seeded"

Tags: boot, 20.04, snap

I just do `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and now I can't enter GUI mode after booting (Yes, I can enter tty1-6 via Ctrl+Alt+F2). The last uprade is about the kernel, I think. Note that this error may differ from:

- [a start job is running for wait unti snapd is fully seeded - 18.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077751/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-unti-snapd-is-fully-seeded-18-04-install)
- [Ubuntu wont load, stuck for over an hour with "Started waiting until snapd is fully seeded"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133993/ubuntu-wont-load-stuck-for-over-an-hour-with-started-waiting-until-snapd-is-fu)
- [Long boot delay on Ubuntu loading/splash screen following regular dist-upgrade on clean SSD install (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o)

Why do I think this problem differs from the previous ones?

- I tried to uninstall snap, disable nvidia persistent and change kernel, but the problem still appears.
- I **can** boot into GUI if I choose recovery model (even with the same kernel)

I also already tried the solutions offered there and nothing works. I am still on this error on boot.

```
[  ok  ]  finished wait until snapd is fully seeded
```

Any offer?

Comment: "nothing works" doesn't mean that it's a different question. Your question should clearly explain how the **question** is different. The single sentence of your description does not give us enough information to understand what your different problem might be.

Comment: Thanks! I added more info. Also, I can confirm now I can enter GUI if I choose recovery mode from grub.

Comment: Im having a similar issue. I've seen this before on older lts versions and adding the nomodeset option has worked in the past. But now that isn't working. Space isn't an issue for my system. So that didn't solve the problem. For now what im doing is just booting into the old kernel. I will probably remove the old. Anyone else able to solve it? Other than remove the hot mess that is snap?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I ran out of disk space.

Solution:

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Use root shell
3. Delete files

Comment: The cause seems many. In my case, the (nvidia) is the culprit. Adding `nomodeset` option in `/etc/default/grub` solves my problem above.

Comment: Also, `nouveau.modeset=0` on the grub setting above works fine and maybe better than nomodeset only (proper resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered exact same problem when I was using `Normal Installation` and check in `Third party software` when installing Ubuntu 20.04.

The issue got resolved after I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 with `Minimal Installation` without check in `Third party software`

I'm not sure where exactly the problem was lying, but hope this helps!