# ubuntu 22.04.1 lts failed to start. wait until snapd is fully seeded

Tags: bug-reporting

Hello i have a problem with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. This problem are: FAILED failed to start Wait until snapd is fully seeded. Pls anyone help me i must have that os for school.
Sorry for English. Im from Poland

Comment: Can you (or anyone else) make sense of this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387858/cannot-enter-gui-with-finished-wait-until-snapd-is-fully-seeded ??