# After installing newest NVIDIA driver, Ubuntu 22.04 will not boot ("Finished: wait until snapd is fully seeded")

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, 22.04

I own a Dell XPS 8960, which comes with a NVIDIA RTX 4070. The XPS came with Windows, but I used a Bootable USB to wipe Windows and install Ubuntu 22.04 instead.

Tonight, I wanted to install CUDA. Here is everything that I did following up to the issue:

- `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` then `sudo apt autoremove`.
- `nvidia-smi` to check the driver versions.
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to check for the recommended NVIDIA driver version.
- `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535` to install the recommended NVIDIA driver.
- `sudo reboot now`

The reboot sent me to a screen filled with tiny lines, the last of which said "Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded". The screen turned black after a while, and nothing else happened.

Here is everything I have tried to fix the issue of my computer no longer booting. **Again, note that I am on a computer that originally came with Windows, but was later wiped and replaced with Ubuntu 22.04**.

- From the comments on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1391604/1719163), I deduced that I would need to set `nouveau.modeset=0` in `/etc/default/grub`.
- To do the above, I tried to boot into the root shell. I tried everything listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/1719163), but nothing worked (it all still went to the "Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded" screen).
- I read that I could try booting into **Recovery mode**. I tried to do so following the instructions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384994/how-do-i-boot-to-recovery-mode-in-ubuntu-20-04), which instructed me to go to the GRUB Menu. However, even though I tried everything to get into the GRUB Menu (which would have an option saying "Advanced options for Ubuntu"), it didn't work. **Below is what I tried to get into the GRUB Menu:**

  - Pressing **F2** got me into **Boot Options** (which listed `ubuntu`, `Onboard NIC (IPV4/6 PXE)` under "UEFI Options", and `BIOS Setup`, `Diagnostics`, and `BIOS Flash Update` under "OTHER OPTIONS"). [image]
  - Pressing **F12** got me into BiOS.

    - The boot order in BiOS seems to be correct; the first priority is called `ubuntu`. Secure Boot is disabled as well.
  - Holding **SHIFT** did nothing.
  - Repeatedly pressing **Esc** gave inconsistent results; I think it depends on when I pressed it.

    - A few times, there would be a flash of what looked like the GRUB Menu, but then it'd go back to the "Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded" screen. In fact, I've found that pressing Esc would switch between that screen and the Dell logo as my computer was trying to boot up.
    - Once, I got to a weird shell that said "GRUB" at the top, and also said **GNU Grub: Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported**. Remembering the first question I had seen, I entered the command `nouveau.modeset=0` and pressed enter. The terminal appeared to accept it, and nothing happened.

      - Then, I restarted the computer. This sent me to **SafetyAssist**, which is a Dell program that scans for hardware/software errors. It appears that entering that command did something really bad. In the end, the software said **"No bootable devices were found"**, and suggested that this was likely caused by a corrupt drive or by an incorrect boot order (and I had already checked the boot order and believed it to be correct).

I truly thank you for taking the time to read this question. Does anyone know **how I can fix this**, and, perhaps, **why this happened**?

(The only possible thought I have for *why* this may have happened: I didn't `purge` all NVIDIA-related files before trying to install the driver. The tutorial I read didn't mention it, but later tutorials I found did)

Comment: In what state is the machine now, does it boot back up at least to pass grub? If so, then to get in the grub menu you may need to _repeatedly_ press they shift key. Once in grub, pick Recovery Mode, and take it from there. If it doesn't boot at all any more, search for how to recover from an unbootable Ubuntu. That question has answers on AskUbuntu.